# Javascript change time between military and AM/PM onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, time

I have a Rails app where I'm displaying a realtime clock in my application layout.  I'm using this code to make it work:

```
<div id="time" class="time_display"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        startTime()
    }, 500);
}
startTime();
</script>
```

What I'd like to be able to do is somehow give the user the option to switch between a realtime clock in military time and regular AM/PM time with the AM/PM included but clicking on the div.

I've done some searching but haven't found anything that works too well.  I'm open to any solutions someone might have be it JS or jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If my question is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Really:

```
var ampm = 'am';
if(hours > 11){
  ampm = 'pm';
  if(hours > 12)hours = hours-12;
}
if(hours === 0)hours = 12;
```

Also, you could do something like:

```
today.toLocaleString().split(',')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code. It get updated only on next tick, but you can manage to fix that if you want

```js
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    var timer = document.getElementById('time');
    if (timer.type == 'r') {
        h = h % 12;
        h = h ? h : 12;
        timer.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + ampm;
    } else
        timer.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        startTime()
    }, 500);
    document.getElementById('time').onclick = function () {
        if (this.type == 'r')
            this.type = 'm';
        else
            this.type = 'r';
    }
}
startTime();
```

```html
<div id="time" class="time_display"></div>
```